# Cypress Drag and drop test

Tags: django, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, cypress

I would like to test the sortable table with Cypress.io

I follow their page instruction: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger.html#Mouse-Events

and it doesn't work...

First: it doesn't move the element

Second: when I see the step by step test on the left side, mouse down and mouse move are located in the same position...

my test

```
cy.get('.resource-filter-table')
        .trigger('mousedown', {witch:1, pageX:188, pageY:196})
        .trigger('mousemove', {witch:1, pageX:188, pageY:261})
        .trigger('mouseup')
```

my html

```
<table class="table table-borderless resource-filter-table">
    <thead>
    <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" checked=True class="resourceFilterElementAll" onchange="checkAllResources(this)"></th>
    <th scope="col">Line</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for linija in user_lines %}
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" checked=True class="resourceFilterElement" onchange="filterOfResources()" id="{{linija.pk}}"></th>
        <th class="filter-list-element">{{ linija.line_name}} <i class="filter-list-icon material-icons">drag_handle</i></th>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `'witch' !== 'which'`, and that only seems to be for *"jQuery UI sortable"*.

Comment: This helps, so that element move, but it doesn't stay on the position (it go back to its first position).