# Trying to write a cypress test for drag and drop to a specific destination

Tags: drag-and-drop, automated-tests, ui-automation, cypress

I am able to drag the content but its dropping in the same location instead of intended location.
My goal is to drop at specific location,which isn't happening.Need some help or suggestion on this!!

My test

```
it('moves the piece when dragged to valid place', function () {
        cy.get('[data-cy="dataExplorer" ]').find('ux-accordion-panel').first().click();
        cy.get('[data-cy="metricContainer"]').first()
        .trigger('mousedown', { button: 0 })
        .wait(1000)
        .trigger('mousemove', {force: true, x: -370, y: 180, bubbles: false})
        .trigger('mouseup', {force: true})
    });
```

My html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody uxTabbableList>
  <tr *ngFor="let field of fields; let i=index" uxTabbableListItem>
    <td class="metric-group" (mouseenter)="activeRowId = field.id"
        (mouseleave)="activeRowId = null" [attr.aria-expanded]="activeRowId === field.id"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['mashup-dashboard']" cdkDropList>
      <div cdkDrag (cdkDragDropped)="dragDropped($event, field)" data-cy="metricContainer" class="metric-container">
        <div data-cy="metricName" class="metric-name">
          <div>{{field.name}}</div>
          <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="drop-preview-placeholder"></div>
          <div *cdkDragPreview>{{field.name}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="add-button-container" [class.flt-show]="activeRowId === field.id">
          <button type="button" aria-label="Edit" class="btn button-primary"
                  [tabindex]="activeRowId === field.id ? 0 : -1" (click)="addMetricPanel(field);">
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326250/cypress-drag-and-drop-test

Comment: @ARao, I checked it.Drag is successful but not the drop.